# Getting Error - PG::UndefinedColumn (ERROR: column d.adsrc does not exist on psql 12 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

[image]

I Am trying to install ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.0 in ubuntu 20.04. rake is not migrating due to the error

```
Error - PG::UndefinedColumn (ERROR: column d.adsrc does not exist
```

```
psql (PostgreSQL) **12.11** (Ubuntu 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

Would you help me with fix to resolve the issue and run the rails migration smoothly

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: you're using the wrong pg ruby gem for the version of the database you're using.

Postgres versions up to 11 have the column `adsrc` in pg_attrdef:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-attrdef.html

Postgres versions after (and including) 12 do not:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/catalog-pg-attrdef.html

you are severely limiting which gem you can use by using the very old and obsolete ruby 1.9.3. you can either look to downgrade your database or upgrade your ruby version.

Comment: Hi @jad, I have downgraded the PostgreSQL to 11 and ruby 1.9.3, rails 3. Now am facing segmentation errors. 

/home/spar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:928: [BUG] Segmentation fault>

Would you please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to recompile your gem. Unusual it and reinstall it and see if that helps. The header files will have changed with the postgres version